# What exactly is the difference between Repartition and RepartitionByExpression in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```scala
  test("distribute above repartition") {
    // Always respects the top distribute and removes useless repartition
    val query1 = testRelation
      .repartition(10)
      .distribute('a)(20)
    val query2 = testRelation
      .repartition(30)
      .distribute('a)(20)

    val optimized1 = Optimize.execute(query1.analyze)
    val optimized2 = Optimize.execute(query2.analyze)
    val correctAnswer = testRelation.distribute('a)(20).analyze

    comparePlans(optimized1, correctAnswer)
    comparePlans(optimized2, correctAnswer)
  }
```

Look over above, it seems `distribute` means repartition by some specific columns(namely partition key from my perspective).

My question is:

- What key would be used for Partitioner when only `repartition`(no `distribute`) invoked?